# How to perform a custom task from a action button click in notification?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-notification-action

I have a notification in my app and I want to perform a custom task on clicking of the action in the notification. I have done this to add a action:

```java
timerNotificationBuilder.addAction(0, "STOP", null /*What to add here ?*/ );
```

But, I want to stop a handler from running on click of this action. I have only seen to open activities using this. But, how to stop a handler or any custom task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sambhav.K , You need to pass Pending Intent in action button like below code

```
  notificationBuilder.addAction(mCallAction)

  val mCallAction = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
            R.drawable.ic_reject_call,
            "Stop",
            mPendingIntent
        )


     val mCallIntent = Intent(context,   CustomActionReceiver::class.java)
   
    val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, 999,
        mCallIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
```

and create new CustomActionReceiver class and do your stuff what you want like below

```
class CustomActionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
   // Do your Stuff
}}
```

Comment: yup. I tried that. It worked. But, how can I pass `Runnable` and `Handler` in `.putExtra()`?

Comment: Why you need Handler or Runnable for action in Notification ?

Comment: I am making and stop watch app and there, when the app closes, the timer continues. For that, I need `startForeground()` in the service which needs a notification. For stopwatch, I use handler and runnable